# Extracting multiple groups from python string with regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract multiple groups from a string and saving them for later så that I can combine them.

Basically I want to go from this:

```
frac{2+2}{9}
to this
(2+2)/(9)
```

I am trying to accomplish this using regex (re) but it seems it cannot save multiple groups from the text to a variable using (?P...) where is saves this part of the string to the variable X. This works fine but when I try to save multiple groups with (?P...) and (?P...) it just returns none.

Is there any way in python to capture multiple groups from a string using regex, storing then to a variable and then using them later?

Right now my code looks like this

```
stringtotest = 'frac{2+2}{9}*29+frac{2+3}{10}*29'
import re

a = re.search('frac{(.+?)}', stringtotest).group(1)
print(a)

b = re.search('backslashfrac{(?:...)}{(.+?)}', stringtotest).group(1)
print(b)
```

And this works just fine but i want to do it more efficiently by doing something like this.

```
string = 'frac{2+2}{9}*29+frac{2+3}{10}*29'
import re

both = re.search('frac{(?P<a>...)}{(?P<b>...)}', string)
print(both.groups(1))
```

But this returns an error.

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't this be much easier?

```
stringtotest = 'frac{2+2}{9}*29+frac{2+3}{10}*29'

to_replace = [("}{", ")/("), ("frac{", "("), ("}", ")")]
for x, y in to_replace:
    stringtotest = stringtotest.replace(x, y)
print(stringtotest)
```